# How to set AWS CloudFront Signed Cookies in Next.js

Tags: next.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk-nodejs

I want to use AWS CloudFront to serve (protected) user content from a S3 bucket. To accomplish this, I would like to use [CloudFront Signed Cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html). I am wondering what the best way is to set those cookies in Next.js using the App Router.

### What I've tried

First, I thought about setting them on every request using middleware, but `getSignedCookies` from `@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer` seems to use the Node.js crypto API, [which is unsupported in Next.js middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/node-module-in-edge-runtime).

Apart from that, it lookies like [setting cookies is only supported in Server Actions or Route Handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies). Making the client call a Server Action or a Route Handler specifically to set cookies does not feel very elegant though, especially, since I would need to make sure to call the Action or the API route before loading my content from CloudFront.

What is the best way to set those cookies?

### Code I used

Here is an outline of the code I was planning to use:

```ts
import { getSignedCookies } from "@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

function setCloudFrontCookies(userId: string) {
  const policy = constructCloudFrontPolicy(userId);

  const keyPairId = process.env.CLOUDFRONT_KEY_PAIR_ID;
  if (!keyPairId) throw new Error("Cloudfront key pair ID is required");
  const privateKey = process.env.CLOUDFRONT_PRIVATE_KEY;
  if (!privateKey) throw new Error("Cloudfront private key is required");

  const signedCookies = getSignedCookies({
    url: `https://example.com/${userId}/*`,
    keyPairId: keyPairId,
    privateKey: privateKey,
    policy: policy
  });

  cookies().set({
    name: "CloudFront-Policy",
    value: signedCookies["CloudFront-Policy"] ?? "",
    ...
  });

  cookies().set({
    name: "CloudFront-Signature",
    ...
  });

  ...
}
```